# MATLAB - Least Squares Fitting for Log - Log Data to find p value.

Tags: logic, logarithms, matlab, random-walk, least-squares

This is part of the code for a random-walk simulation.

- To test the code, I'm using steps=[30]; there will be more values, but I want to run it for 1 trial to decrease code processing.
- `log_steps = log(1:steps);` <--- corresponds to the log (steps vector) for the x axis of the plot
- `log_AVG = log(d_AVG);` <---- corresponds to the log (average steps sizes) for the y axis of the plot

**The intended approach**
[d~sqrt(N) to  find model's p value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI9yj.png)
**to prove that $p$ which represents the probability of any step (forward || backward) is 0.5**.

PROBLEM: the program's p value estimation is 10x larger than it should be. It gives a value between 4 to 5 for p, when p should be about 0.5.

**where is the logic wrong? Relevant code below.**

```
    figure(i+10);
    hold on;
    loglog(log_steps, log_AVG,'-s');
    %loglog(1:steps(i), d_AVG, '-s');
```

`N=log_steps;`
  `c= log_AVG;`

```
    p = polyfit(N, c,0);
    f = (c.* (N.^p));
    hold on;
    loglog(N, f);
    hold off;
    end;
```

["hyperbolic curve" <--- log-log plot of 30 step random walk without polyfit attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ1QH.png)

["straight horizontal line" <-- log-log plot of ONLY randomwalk points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRFa.png)